# Parse the HTTP_COOKIES string from Apache for use in #if clause

Tags: apache, http, cookies, ssi

I want to be able to read the cookies from Apache's HTTP_COOKIE string and then add includes based on the contents of that string.

I've got this far:

```
<!--#set var="cookies" value="HTTP_COOKIE" -->
<p>COOKIES:  <!--#echo var="$cookies"--></p>
```

which gives me a string with all the cookies in it.

Now I want to be able to parse the string for something like `Name=Bob`.

I thought I'd be able to do this:

```
<!--#if expr="$cookies = /Name=([a-zA-Z]+)/"-->
<p>Your name is <!--#echo var="$1"--></p>
<!--#endif-->
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What should I be doing -- or isn't this possible?

Comment: There seems to be a "]" missing in the expression, how about "/Name=([a-zA-Z]+)/"? Or is it just a typo in the question?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was just a typo. I tried various things, and there were valid regex in at least some of them!

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible -- see the `get_include_var` function of `mod_include.c`.

Perhaps your regular expression needs some tweaking.

Comment: I can absolutely assure you that I tried with just about every form of regex known to personkind. Including no-brainers like just `[a-z]`